# Update User Location In Parse Using Xcode 8 and Swift 3

Tags: ios, parse-platform, swift3, xcode8, parse-server

I am running **Parse Server** and trying to log a user in and then **update their location**. Right now I am just manually creating a **PFGeoPoint** and then trying to add it to the key "**location**" which I have already added on Parse Server as a PFGeoPoint. When I run the following code I receive an error.

```
 let currentUser = PFUser.logInWithUsername(inBackground: "test", password: "test")
 let point = PFGeoPoint(latitude: 25.000, longitude: 25.000)
 currentUser.setValue(point, forKey:"location")
```

The error is as follows:

```
'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<BFTask 0x60000067da00> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key location.'
```

How can I resolve this error? Any help would be much appreciated!
I am using Xcode 8 and Swift 3.

Comment: PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground { (geoPoint: PFGeoPoint?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    print("got location successfully")
                    PFUser.currentUser()!.setValue(geoPoint, forKey:"location")
                    PFUser.currentUser()!.saveInBackground()

                } else {
                    print(error)
                }
            }

Comment: @himanshu: if that comment was meant to be an answer, you should make it an answer(with a bit of explanation as to why it will work). Otherwise, I don't understand the comment at all.

Comment: @rici check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground { 
    (geoPoint: PFGeoPoint?, error: NSError?) -> Void in 
          if error == nil { 
               print("got location successfully") 
               PFUser.currentUser()!.setValue(geoPoint, forKey:"location") PFUser.currentUser()!.saveInBackground() 
          } else { 
               print(error) 
          } 
 }
```

here is method that is use for find the user current location and pass that data to your server with your PFGeoPoint that task is perform in Background. here i also mention that if your location changes or get it so in server  PFUser update their location with new one . hope you are little clear about this.

**thank you.**